# awk mirror (reverse) rows

Tags: perl, awk, row

I want to reverse rows (single word) of the file.

```
cat dummy

Hugo
Dumas
Camus
```

Wanted output looks like this:

```
Hugo oguH
Dumas samuD
Camus sumaC
```

Probably it's easiest to do with awk, but perl oneliner would be grate too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need for `perl` or `awk`, just use `paste` and `rev`, and process substitution (otherwise just use a temp file):

```
paste -d ' ' file <(rev file)
```

Results:

```
Hugo oguH
Dumas samuD
Camus sumaC
```

Comment: Can I ask why using only rev it reverse all file (upside down) & when using this command order stays the same?

Comment: @Poe: `rev` will flip each line of a file on a vertical axis. Don't get this confused with `tac` (which will reverse the order of lines in a file). The command above uses `paste` to join each line of the original file with it's vertically opposed counterpart (i.e. the output of `rev`). `paste` simply works to join two (or more) files side-by-side. HTH.

Comment: Or: `rev file | paste -d ' ' file -`  No need for process substitution or tmp file.

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{
    row = $0
    s = ""
    for (i = length(row); i > 0; --i)
        s = s substr(row, i, 1)
    print row " " s
}
```

For every line in the input, loop over the characters taking a length-1 substring from each position and concatenate to make the reversed string.  Then print row, a space, and the reversed string.

Easier in Python!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    row = line.strip()
    print(row + ' ' + row[::-1])
```

For each line in standard input, strip white space to get rid of the newline.  Then print the row, a space, and the row reversed.  It's reversed using a "slice" with default beginning and end, but a step of -1 to make the slice get the characters in reverse.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ perl -pi -le '$_ .= $" . reverse' file.txt
```

Explanation (see [`perldoc perlrun`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html) for more details):

- **`-p`**: process and print file in line-by-line mode
- **`-i`**: enable in-place editing
- **`-l`**: automatically process line endings (implicitly `chomp`s when used with `-p` and appends `$\` as well
- **`$"`**: another way to write `' '` as its default value is a space
- **`$_ .= $" . reverse`**

  `$_` corresponds to the string contained by the line (minus the `chomp`-ed line-ending). So here, `.=` concatenates to `$_` a single space (`$"`), followed by the `reverse`-d string. Note that there is no need to specify `reverse($_)` explicitly since in scalar context `reverse()` reverses `$_` if no arguments are specified.

Answer (score 1):

with sed one liner

`sed '/\n/!G;s/\(.\)\(.*\n\)/&\2\1/;//D;s/.//'`